# React Native Upgrade to 0.66 - Issue with UMReactNativeAdapter - UMModuleRegistry

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-unimodules

I'm trying to upgrade my React Native App from 0.63.3 to 0.66.4 following this guideline
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.3&to=0.66.4 for upgrade.

I stumble upon this issue during building process on iOS

[image: UMReactNativeAdapter UMModuleRegistry]

I believe this error might also be related to Expo as i'm in bare workflow, implementing react-native-unimodules. It seems that UMReactNativeAdapter is related to it.

```
"react-native-unimodules": "^0.11.0"
```

Seems like the version could be the problem, but we shouldn't update it manually i guess

If you have encounters this issue, or found a way to fix it, please feel free to add any suggestions.

Thanks for your time

Comment: have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Nope. We didn't yet

Comment: I have found a way to bypass it by migrating to expo modules from unimodules

Comment: Yes that is what i thought. We will try to update it first to expo modules, then upgrade the react native version